React Infinite Query with Optimistic Update
Utilizing Optimistic Updates with React Infinite Query
I have a chat list, i use React Infinite Query to get the list and i want to send a message but it takes sometime to be posted on the list, what i am trying to do is use React Query Optimistic UI to update the UI immediately but it didn't work
ChatList Component
import type { Conversation, IChatParticipant } from 'src/types/chat-system/types';

import { useMemo, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useInfiniteQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';

import { Stack, LinearProgress, CircularProgress } from '@mui/material';

import { useMessagesScroll } from 'src/hooks/chat-system/use-messages-scroll';

import { getMessages } from 'src/services/chat-system/service';

import { Scrollbar } from '../shared/scrollbar';
import { ChatMessageItem } from './chat-message-item';
import { Lightbox, useLightBox } from '../shared/lightbox';

type Props = {
  participants: IChatParticipant[];
  selectedConversation: Conversation;
};

export function ChatMessageList({ participants, selectedConversation }: Props) {

  const { data, fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetchingNextPage, isLoading } = useInfiniteQuery({
    queryKey: ['messages', selectedConversation.id],
    queryFn: ({ pageParam = 0 }) => getMessages(selectedConversation.slug, pageParam, 10),
    getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => {
      const nextPage = lastPage.meta.current_page;
      return nextPage <= lastPage.meta.last_page ? nextPage : undefined;
    },
    initialPageParam: 0,
  });


  const messages = useMemo(() => data?.pages.flatMap((page) => page.data).reverse() || [], [data]);

  const slides = messages.map((message) => ({ src: message.message }));

  const lightbox = useLightBox(slides);

  const { messagesEndRef } = useMessagesScroll(messages);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleScroll = (e: any) => {
      const { scrollTop } = e.currentTarget;

      if (scrollTop === 0 && hasNextPage && !isFetchingNextPage) {
        fetchNextPage();
      }
    };

    const scrollContainer = messagesEndRef.current;
    scrollContainer?.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
    return () => scrollContainer?.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
  }, [fetchNextPage, hasNextPage, isFetchingNextPage, messagesEndRef]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return (
      <Stack sx={{ flex: '1 1 auto', position: 'relative' }}>
        <LinearProgress
          color="inherit"
          sx={{
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: 1,
            height: 2,
            borderRadius: 0,
            position: 'absolute',
          }}
        />
      </Stack>
    );
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Scrollbar ref={messagesEndRef} sx={{ px: 3, pt: 5, pb: 3, flex: '1 1 auto' }}>
        {isFetchingNextPage && (
          <Stack sx={{ mb: 2 }} direction="row" justifyContent="center">
            <CircularProgress size={20} />
          </Stack>
        )}

        {messages?.map((message, idx) => (
          <ChatMessageItem
            key={message.id || idx}
            message={message}
            participants={participants}
            onOpenLightbox={() => lightbox.onOpen(message.message)}
            loading={message.loading}
          />
        ))}

        {/* {variables.length > 0 &&
          variables.map((item, idx) => (
            <ChatMessageItem
              key={idx}
              message={item.data.message!}
              participants={[]}
              onOpenLightbox={() => {}}
              loading
            />
          ))} */}
      </Scrollbar>

      <Lightbox
        slides={slides}
        open={lightbox.open}
        close={lightbox.onClose}
        index={lightbox.selected}
      />
    </>
  );
}

ChatInput Component
import type { Conversation, IChatParticipant } from 'src/types/chat-system/types';

import { useRef, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { useMutation, useQueryClient } from '@tanstack/react-query';

import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import InputBase from '@mui/material/InputBase';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';

import { useAuthContext } from 'src/hooks/auth/use-auth-context';

import { sendMessage } from 'src/services/chat-system/service';

import { Iconify } from '../shared/iconify';

type Props = {
  disabled: boolean;
  recipients: IChatParticipant[];
  selectedConversation: Conversation;
  onAddRecipients: (recipients: IChatParticipant[]) => void;
};

export function ChatMessageInput({
  disabled,
  recipients,
  onAddRecipients,
  selectedConversation,
}: Props) {
  const fileRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const { user } = useAuthContext();
  const handleAttach = useCallback(() => {
    if (fileRef.current) {
      fileRef.current.click();
    }
  }, []);

  const { mutate: sendMessageMutation } = useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['sendMessage'],
    mutationFn: sendMessage,

    onMutate: async (data) => {
      // Cancel any ongoing fetch for the current query
      await queryClient.cancelQueries({ queryKey: ['messages', selectedConversation.id] });

      // Snapshot the previous messages for rollback
      const previousMessages = queryClient.getQueryData(['messages', selectedConversation.id]);

      // Optimistically update the cache
      queryClient.setQueryData(['messages', selectedConversation.id], (oldData: any) => {
        if (!oldData) return null;

        const newMessage = {
          id: Math.random(), // Temporary ID until server assigns one
          message: data.data.message,
          senderId: user?.id || 1,
          createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
          loading: true,
        };
        console.log('first', () => ({
          ...oldData,
          pages: oldData.pages.map((page: any, index: number) => {
            // Add the new message to the first page
            if (index === oldData.pages.length - 1) {
              return {
                ...page,
                data: page.data.push(newMessage),
              };
            }
            return page;
          }),
        }));
        return {
          ...oldData,
          pages: oldData.pages.map((page: any, index: number) => {
            // Add the new message to the first page
            if (index === oldData.pages.length - 1) {
              return {
                ...page,
                data: page.data.push(newMessage),
              };
            }
            return page;
          }),
        };
      });

      return { previousMessages }; // Return snapshot for rollback
    },

    onError: (error, newMessage, context) => {
      console.error('Failed to send message', error);
      // Rollback to previous state
      queryClient.setQueryData(['messages', selectedConversation.id], context?.previousMessages);
    },

    onSettled: () => {
      // Refetch the messages after the mutation is settled
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['messages', selectedConversation.id] });
    },
  });

  const handleChangeMessage = useCallback((event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleSendMessage = useCallback(
    (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if (event.key !== 'Enter' || !message.trim()) return;
      sendMessageMutation({ data: { message }, conversationSlug: selectedConversation.slug });
      setMessage('');
    },
    [message, selectedConversation, sendMessageMutation]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <InputBase
        name="chat-message"
        id="chat-message-input"
        value={message}
        onKeyUp={handleSendMessage}
        onChange={handleChangeMessage}
        placeholder="Type a message"
        disabled={disabled}
        startAdornment={
          <IconButton>
            <Iconify icon="eva:smiling-face-fill" />
          </IconButton>
        }
        endAdornment={
          <Stack direction="row" sx={{ flexShrink: 0 }}>
            <IconButton onClick={handleAttach}>
              <Iconify icon="solar:gallery-add-bold" />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton onClick={handleAttach}>
              <Iconify icon="eva:attach-2-fill" />
            </IconButton>
            <IconButton>
              <Iconify icon="solar:microphone-bold" />
            </IconButton>
          </Stack>
        }
        sx={{
          px: 1,
          height: 56,
          flexShrink: 0,
          borderTop: (theme) => `solid 1px ${theme.vars.palette.divider}`,
          mt: 'auto',
        }}
      />

      <input type="file" ref={fileRef} style={{ display: 'none' }} />
    </>
  );
}

